# Uploadify Change file metadata onselect

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, uploadify

I am trying to upload files to amazon S3 with uploadify, which I am currently doing "successfully". The file gets up there, but w/o it content-type. I am trying to figure out how one can add manually the content-type using onselect and have not had any success.

I am not sure if this is the best way, I am trying it based of the advice from the second answer in this post - [Uploadify uploading arbitrary file to s3 with correct Content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228142/uploadify-uploading-arbitrary-file-to-s3-with-correct-content-type) (It is the same problem as mine)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never was able to figure out how to do this with uploadify, so instead I used functionality in the AWS PHP Library (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsPHP/latest/DeveloperGuide/welcome.html) to manipulate the file how I needed it to be after it was already uploaded.